# Update model hook value after button click and taking new value from input text

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Newcomer here,

```
async model() {

let response = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid=[APIKeyPlaceholder]);

var data = await response.json();

return data;

}
```

I am using openweathermap api to get current weather data and passing city argument in the api.

I am taking this `data` value and displaying it on `.hbs` file. Now I have added an input text field and button for entering city name. How do I update the city name and model hook value(i.e data value is updated return from api fetch command) with the new value I take from `.hbs` file ?

Do I use controller? How do I bind input to ember variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you persist the city in the URL. This will allow the user to bookmark and share the view for a specific city. Additionally it will allow you to configure the route to rerun the model hook automatically whenever the value of the query parameter changes.

1. Register a query parameter. This currently requires a controller:

   ```js
   import Controller from '@ember/controller';

   export default class ArticlesController extends Controller {
     queryParams = ['city'];
   }
   ```
2. Use the query parameter in the `model` hook of the route. It's passed as part of the params object passed in as first argument.

   ```js
   async model({ city }) {
     let response = await fetch(
       `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=[APIKeyPlaceholder]`
     );
     const data = await response.json();
     return data;
   }
   ```
3. Configure the route to rerun the `model` hook whenever the value of the `city` query paramter changes:

   ```js
   import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

   export default class ArticlesRoute extends Route {
     queryParams = {
       city: {
         refreshModel: true
       }
     };
   }
   ```
4. Update the `city` query parameter by triggering a transition. I'm illustrating this using a component. But the same approach works in a controller, route or even a service as it only relies on the [`transitionTo` method of the `RouterService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.23/classes/RouterService/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo).

   ```js
   import Component from '@glimmer/component';
   import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

   export default class MyComponent extends Component {
     @service router;

     @action
     changeCity(city) {
       // This update query parameters of the current route.
       // If you want to redirect to another route, you can
       // pass the route and optional models as additional
       // arguments _before_ the options object.
       this.router.transitionTo({ queryParams: { city }});
     }
   }
   ```

Please find more details and explanation in the [Query Parameter chapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/) of the official guides for Ember.js.